# ASP.NET Core: log all requests (reading body twice) EnableRewind not working for [FromBody] attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am following [this post](https://elanderson.net/2017/02/log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/) how to log all requests.

But this code:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    await this.LogRequest(context.Request);

    await this._next(context);
}

private async Task LogRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    var body = request.Body;
    request.EnableRewind();

    var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
    await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    request.Body = body;
}
```

doesn't work, because I get

```
"A non-empty request body is required."
```

in Controller with `[ApiController]` attribute

```
[HttpPut("MyMethod")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> MyMethod([FromBody]MyArgs model)
{
    //...
}
```

I am trying to do all sorts of combinations

```
    string bodyAsText = null;
    if (request.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var body = request.Body;
        request.EnableRewind();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            bodyAsText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        request.Body = body;
    }
```

but nothing works. What am I missing here? There is some answer with similar solution on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EnableRewind), but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my case.

If I comment code for reading body, it works.

Comment: Yea of course its not working, you are restoring the original stream back at `request.Body = body;` and the middleware called afterwards tries to read the already read network stream. `EnableRewind` replaces the internal Stream with a rewindable one (thats read inmemory and then rewinded from there)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/BufferingHelper.cs#L41-L79) what EnableRewind actually does

Answer (score 5):

I was waiting for Tseng to post an answer as he already point me to a problem and solution in comment. But since he didn't do it, I will try to answer based on comment and debugging experience.

As Tseng mention `EnableRewind` should be called before `var body = request.Body;`

This code:

```
if (request.ContentLength > 0)
{
    request.EnableRewind();
    var body = request.Body;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
         bodyAsText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
         request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
    request.Body = body;
}
```

throws error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'FileBufferingReadStream'.

in line `await this._next(context);`.

**Working code is:**

```
if (request.ContentLength > 0)
{
    request.EnableRewind();
    var body = request.Body;

    var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
    await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    request.Body = body;
}
```

Thank you @Tseng.

Comment: Yea you don't need to dispose it (that's what using does), the streams get disposed at the end of the request, when the response is sent. You should maybe just not allocate the whole buffer at the same time, as that can consume a lot of memory (i.e. right now 3x of the content size right now: If you have 10 mb payload, that would be 10 mb for the buffer and ~20 mb for the `bodyAsText` string, since strings are utf-16). You can also remove `var body = request.Body` and `request.Body = body;` in both samples and additionally the using statement in the first